# How to run an c# project in node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-mvc-4, ionic-framework

I have made an simple Ionic app, using c# in the backend and angularjs in front end. 
I was running it in visual studio. How can I compile it with node.js and ionic cordova?

I am not familiar with node.js so I can't understand if this can be done or not?

Comment: Node.js is framework itself, AFAIK this wont possible..

Comment: @pankajparkar: Wrong.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking whether Javascript code can send HTTP requests to a C# server?

Comment: My question is can I compile my ionic app on node.js

Answer (score 0):

If you made your app with angular.js on the front end, that will be your ionic/cordova app. You can keep using your C# backend, since that code runs on the server side.

What you are really doing with ionic/cordova is to build a mobile front-end for your site.

But if you really want to have your back-end running in node.js there's no way but rewriting your back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps, assuming you are running Windows -

a) Install Node.js

b) For any reason you don't have Ionic installed, open cmd and run this -

```
:\>npm install -g ionic
```

c) Now run this command to install cordova

```
:\>npm install -g cordova
```

Now, you have the environment set up to run your ionic app.

d) Change to the directory of your Ionic app and run serve -

```
:\>cd IonicApp
:\IonicApp>ionic serve
```

This should get your app up and running.

**Note:** Now you might have to convert your C# code into an API in order to talk to it from your Angular/Ionic app.

Comment: Oh I see .OK, I will try the steps and see if I can do it. Lucky, I have only one controller in c# the rest is all angularjs

Comment: Did you get it running?